# С чем связанно что нету хостингов , nginx+apache (я не могу ни одного найти)?

Tags: apache, веб-программирование, nginx, хостинг

С чем связанно что нету хостингов, которые работают в связке, nginx+apache (я не могу ни одного найти)?

Comment: Зачем связывать два web-сервера?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос не связан с программированием или администрированием

Comment: @VenZell Например :  Почему нету хостингов -   потому что эта плохая практика. администрирования и програмирования

Comment: Ваше пояснение не делает ваш вопрос относящимся к тематике администрирования или программирования. К тому же вопрос слишком общий и ответы будут основаны на мнениях, а не знаниях.

Comment: @VenZell Ответы могут быть основаны и на знаниях. В любом вопросе, ответ может быть основан как на личном мнении, так и на знаниях. Луше помогите ответить на вопрос . Приятного вам дня.

Comment: На ваш ответ невозможно дать вопрос основанный на знаниях, если он не будет дан сотрудником сразу нескольких хостеров. А вопросы, ответы на которые могут быть даны основываясь только на мнении на данном ресурсе не вписываются в формат.

Comment: @VenZell Я надеюсь что тут будет отвечать тот человек, который владеет достоверной информацией. Так-же можно обвенить автора люьбого вопроса, что там будут не соответсвующие ответы. Я думаю, за этим уже как и сам автор должен следить, так и сама администрация. Это - флуд

Comment: Боюсь, вы меня неверно понимаете. На ваш вопрос нельзя дать однозначно верный ответ. Я говорю лишь об этом. И для любого вопроса так сказать нельзя.

Comment: @VenZell - А вы как думаете? Как вы могли бы ответить на этот вопрос?   Вам же не обязательно давать свой ответ в виде ответа, если вы в нём не уверенны.

Comment: Еще раз повторяю, подобные вопросы, на которые нельзя дать однозначно верный ответ на данном ресурсе неформат. У меня нет достоверного ответа на ваш вопрос, поэтому я не буду отвечать вовсе.

Comment: @VenZell Почему нельзя дать однозначный ответ? Можете описать вклатце. Может мне действительно стоит обратиться к администрации по поводу его удаления.

Comment: @VenZell Может тогда ответите в пределах своих знаний? То есть, ответ в виде коментария.

Comment: потому что ответ будет зависеть от предпочтений отвечающего

Comment: @Bald Я читал что связка nginx+apache лучше чем просто apache. Он намного быстрее работает.

Comment: @VenZell ВОРОН - если у вас restfull-сервис, то разницы большой не вижу, но если у вас сайт (а для чего еще хостинг нужен?), тогда вам надо отдавать еще и статику, но у apache с этим проблемы. Поэтому делают связку - nginx отдает статику, а страницы проксирует на апач. Правда, чем плох только nginx + php_fpm сразу так и не скажу, может быть и ничем –

Comment: @gilo1212, это не ответ на ваш вопрос. Мне показалось, что в комменте вы спрашивали чем apache + nginx лучше просто apache, я и ответил. Но я не знаю почему так мало таких хостингов, спрашивать надо у их владельцев. Здесь же можно только привести хостинги с требуемой вам поддержкой (как в ответе), но сказать почему другие хостинги этого не дают мы не можем

Comment: @BOPOH Это не был ответ. Я этой информацией уже давно обладал.

Comment: @BOPOH Большое спасибо вам за ответы и комментарии. Я думаю что плотнее займусь этим вопрососм чуть-чуть позже. Всего вам доброго.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так полно их, просто плохо ищете наверное. Правда, не везде можно настройки гибко править, ограниченность функционала популярных панелей управления сказывается. Вот какие я знаю хостинги с Apache и Nginx:
Ru-Center, Beget, Masterhost.ru, Rusonyx.ru, Sprinthost.ru, Unihost.com, Timeweb.
Есть еще Elasticweb, там только Nginx.

Comment: Подскажите, а почему их так мало? Чем это можно объяснить? Почему все не передут на  Apache + Nginx модель?

Comment: @gilo1212 а почему кто то должен перейти на указанную Вами связку?! инструменты выбираются исходя из требований и предпочтений

Comment: @gilo1212 берете VPS/VDS и делаете там всё, что душе угодно. Хоть пельмени варите

Comment: @Bald Скажите пожалуйста, разве эта `Apache + Nginx`  связка не лучше просто `Apache`

Comment: @gilo1212 по вашей логике связка `php + java + nodejs + python` лучше, чем один только `php`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, действительно лучше :) не хватает только `c#+ruby+erlang` :-)

Comment: можете ответить на простой вопрос: *Для чего лучше?*

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский я вас не могу понять. Немогли бы вы вырвзиться яснее?

Comment: @gilo1212, если у вас restfull-сервис, то разницы большой не вижу, но если у вас сайт (а для чего еще хостинг нужен?), тогда вам надо отдавать еще и статику, но у apache с этим проблемы. Поэтому делают связку - nginx отдает статику, а страницы проксирует на апач. Правда, чем плох только nginx + php_fpm сразу так и не скажу, может быть и ничем

Comment: @Bald лучше , например более качественее. Вот как - запарожец и бмв. Apache + Nginx - работает же быстрее чем  Apache.

Comment: @BOPOH Я об этом в курсе , спасибо. Похоже вы тоже из не многих в курсе вопроса.

Comment: @ВОРОН Nginx + php_fpm не плохой вариант, но не так привычен, как Nginx + Apache с его mod_rewrite и htaccess, по которым полно документации, примеров и готовых конфигов для разных CMS.

Comment: @AndrewHobbit, я пока не видел ничего из *mod_rewrite и htaccess*, чтобы нельзя было сделать на nginx. Единственное - nginx приходится перезагружать для этого, в то время как апач на лету htaccess подхватывает. Из недостатков я вижу только это, возможно, есть что-то еще о чем я не знаю

Comment: @ВОРОН Я тоже не видел, но найти инфу по использованию htaccess (особенно на русском языке) проще. Да и дело привычки. Nginx позволяет перечитать конфиг без перезагрузки и потери соединений.

Comment: @gilo1212 Хостинг-провайдер - это компания, зарабатывающая на предоставлении услуг, и поэтому очень многое зависит не от инженеров, которые знают, что это хорошо, правильно, эффективно и т.д., а от экономистов, для которых надо обосновать необходимость трат, вложений и инвестиций. "Просто добавить Nginx", как и любой другой элемент в цепочку, это потратить деньги на персонал, ПО, обучение, планирование, доработку и т.д.. Обосновать получается не всегда.

Comment: @AndrewHobbit, эм... а поподробнее? Я насколько знаю - он перезагружается. Да, это со стороны вроде как не заметно, но он перезагружается. Точнее - запускает второй инстанс с новым конфигом, завершает обработку всех старых соединений и работает на новом инстансе, но главное - это именно перезапуск. Да и не всегда удобно из-за маленького изменения перечитывать весь конфиг. Там может кто-нить не то сделал, а вы этот конфиг перечитали.

Comment: Главный процесс не перезапускается, он проверяет правильность нового конфига, и если все ок, создает новые рабочие и плавно завершает старые. Да, не удобно перечитывать весь конфиг, но быстро и эффективно.

Comment: @Andrew Hobbit Спасибо за ваш ответ. Сразу чуствуется профессионализм.